# Interractive, fourth wall styles . . . What do people think?

Tags: creative-writing

I've set up my 1st person narrator as a particular type of character. She's the type of person who sits next you on a bus or a train. You make the mistake of being polite and exchange pleasantries. She then believes you and her are new 'besties' and proceeds to tell you her entire life story (including all the inappropriate bits).

This technique lends itself to the (do, while) method. e.g the character can be telling you the story whilst getting dressed for work. The getting dressed can take several chapters.

The fourth aspect is highlighted in a particular scene.

The character is having sex with her boyfriend. At the same time she's telling you (the reader)about her visit to the dermatologist. Her boyfriend notices she's distracted (because she's talking to you). He accuses her seeing somebody else - a huge argument ensues.

- Does this style of story-telling off-putting?

Comment: Well, for what it's worth. I like the sound of this. I've read stuff like it before, and it can be brilliant if done well (thought it *has* to be done well, I think, if it isn't to be jarring). That said, this question is way, way too subjective, and I don't think it's on-topic for this site. See: https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I had a quick look . . . and whilst the the question may not be run-of-the-mill I believe it to be within the range. I agree the question is aimed more at readers and is more of a poll than a question. Some readers cannot abide to be taken out of the story.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is a Your Mileage May Vary question. It might work, it might not, but there's no blanket rule, and no Official Answer we could give.

Comment: Yeah, my issue *is* that this is a poll rather than a directly answerable question. I say I like it, someone else says 'no, never do that', another person says 'well you can, but you'll alienate such and such group of readers and is it really worth it?', etc. No one of these answers is any better (at least, as a direct answer to your question) than any other.

Comment: If you ask how to avoid alienating readers while writing something like this, there might be an answerable question in there. Asking about existing fourth-wall-breaking fiction and the techniques it uses to keep readers engaged might also be on topic. Like I said, I like your concept, so I *want* this question to stay, I just think it needs to change emphasis a little.

Comment: Just shooting the breeze with Termite and Lauren. I'm new to this site but I find myself answering many questions with: "There is no right or wrong way but . . . ."

Whilst the primary activity is (and should be) more experienced members answering questions for those less confident. I see no harm in the more experienced debating the merit of techniques. Otherwise what stimulation do they have?

Comment: @Surtsey There may not be an absolute right or wrong in most cases. But what there certainly is is proven and unproven. There are things that we can be confident will work because there are numerous examples of them working. And while the negative case is slightly less certain -- you might be able to make something work that has never been made to work before -- it is highly unlikely, and people should generally be advised against trying unless making that thing work is the whole point of their work. Saying there are no rules, therefore, is not helpful. We deal in precedents and conventions.

Comment: @Mark Now you're going into very core of novel writing theory. In recent years the industry has been plagued by vampire stories and fantasy writers - the theory being what worked for Meyer, Rowling & Rice then will work for new writers now. Evidence says it doesn't. 1 million Hemingway impressionists have tried and failed! Swain & Blake Snyder maybe technique gurus but both have failed in practice. In the same mould Robert McKee has never produced a significant script. Any writer can make anything 'work', when they do it will be taught as the new way.

But it'll only ever work for 'them'.

Comment: @Surtsey Teacher and practitioner are not the same thing. McKee's students have produced many significant scripts. But the thing is, if you are right and there is no valid theory and if anything can be made to work, but only by that one writer, then this site is pointless. So maybe it is pointless, but even if it is, your coming here and telling us so in every question is simply discourteous. If you think there is no good to be done here, fine. But there is no need to keep telling us so. That is just vandalism.

Comment: McKee's students have produced results based on scale. If the princess kisses enough frogs the number say she'll snog a couple princes. 

And, no, my answers are not 'discourteous'. Parroting popular advice from 'how to' books is discourteous. On the other hand telling a new writer, "I'm not convinced but if think you make it work - have at it", IMO opinion is 'confidence building'.

I'm not here to have my ego stroked. I can answer questions with what King said or what Vonnegut said - those answers render the site pointless. Users can look them up on the net.

Comment: @Surtsey I would say that if what works for a given writer will only work for them, that in itself is valid writing advice (i.e. that we should try to find the thing that only works for us). That then raises questions about how to find "what works for you". In other words, whatever the nature of writing (or, I suspect, any human pursuit) there will always be questions that can be asked and answered.

Comment: @Surtsey Also, just because imitation doesn't result in good writing, that doesn't mean there's nothing to be learnt from previous successes. I wouldn't regard a person who only cooked from recipes as a "great chef"; ultimately, the magic has to come from them; but that doesn't mean cooking can't be tought, or that valid questions can't be asked about it.

Comment: @Termite - Hell yes.100%. The majority of the learning experience is finding out 'what kind of writer you are'. But on what I'll call 'our level' we can shoot the breeze, and decide - I'm not going to write it that way because Hemingway did - I'm 'like' Termite threatened a scene, dropped it, threatened it again . . . that tantalizing thing - I think I'll try that.

Ultimately, some writers are looking for a (false) cribsheet - the formula to make money. Others are looking for the best way to express themselves.

Comment: @Surtsey Well, I understood your first three sentences, and I understood the last two. I'm afraid you failed to express yourself (at least to me) with the one(s?) inbetween.

Answer (score 2):

Is this style of storytelling offputting? Yes. All styles of storytelling are offputting to somebody. For a given technique, there will be people who just plain don't like it, and won't be swayed. If you're planning to use the technique regardless, there's little point worrying about these people. If you want to please these people (i.e. attract these people as readers) *and* use this technique, you'll have to decide what you care about more, and make a choice.

A lot of people, however, keep a somewhat open mind about such things. They'll be willing to accept an unusual technique as long as it's worth their while, and especially if it feels like there's a reason for it. If the technique you use feels integral to the story, and helps to communicate things which would be less efficiently communicated without it, then it will feel in-some-way natural regardless of whether the reader is used to it. Even if it *isn't* integral to the story, if it's enough fun to read, that might not matter for a lot of people.

As for whether you *should* use it, that's up to you. It depends on your personal goals, preferences and preoccupations.